# Unmarshal JSON with unknown field name

Tags: json, go

I have a JSON object, something like this:

```
{
    "randomstring": {
        "everything": "here",
        "is": "known"
    }
}
```

Basically everything inside the `randomstring` object is known, I can model that, but the *randomstring* itself is random. I know what it's going to be, but it's different every time. Basically all the data I need is in the *randomstring* object. How could I parse this kind of JSON to get the data?

Comment: Unmarshal into a `map[string]SomeParticularStructType`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a map where the key type is `string` and the value type is a struct with the fields you want, like in [this example on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Lf8FqSz7eY) and below:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Item struct{ X int }

var x = []byte(`{
    "zbqnx": {"x": 3}
}`)

func main() {
    m := map[string]Item{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(x, &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```